# Data memory unit

Tags: verilog, mips32

I started Verilog a few weeks ago and now I'm implementing MIPS pipelining on an FPGA board and I'm on the MEM part of the pipelining stage. I'm trying to code the Data memory unit (in picture -> Data memory Unit).

[image: Snapshot]

I don't understand the use of memread. I understand that if memwrite is 1, the contents of the current address is passed to read data.

So far, this is my code:

```
module data_memory (
input wire [31:0] addr,             // Memory Address
input wire [31:0] write_data,       // Memory Address Contents
input wire memwrite, memread,
output reg [31:0] read_data     // Output of Memory Address Contents
);

reg [31:0] MEMO[0:255];  // 256 words of 32-bit memory

integer i;

initial begin

   read_data <= 0;

   for (i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1)
     MEMO[i] = i;

   end

always @ (addr) begin

   //**I don't understand the use of memread**//

   if (memwrite == 1'b1)
       MEMO[addr] <= write_data;
   end
end

assign read_data = MEMO[addr];

endmodule
```

Do I need another if statement for the memread? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the design you have coded above, you dont use `memread`, instead choosing to combinationally read from the memory via the last line of your module. And without more details on how exactly the memory in your diagram is suppose to function, its difficult to say the exact usage of `memread`. Typical memories only have a `memwrite` and assume that if an address is supplied and `memwrite` is deasserted, the access is a read. In this case, I can only assuming `memread` should be asserted to read from the memory. Also, I would suggest a few edits to your code to make it work better and follow a better synchronous design style (this will incorporate `memread` so you can see how it can be used):

```
module data_memory (
input wire [31:0] addr,          // Memory Address
input wire [31:0] write_data,    // Memory Address Contents
input wire memwrite, memread,
input wire clk,                  // All synchronous elements, including memories, should have a clock signal
output reg [31:0] read_data      // Output of Memory Address Contents
);

reg [31:0] MEMO[0:255];  // 256 words of 32-bit memory

integer i;

initial begin
  read_data <= 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1) begin
    MEMO[i] = i;
  end
end

// Using @(addr) will lead to unexpected behavior as memories are synchronous elements like registers
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (memwrite == 1'b1) begin
    MEMO[addr] <= write_data;
  end
  // Use memread to indicate a valid address is on the line and read the memory into a register at that address when memread is asserted
  if (memread == 1'b1) begin
    read_data <= MEMO[addr];
  end
end

endmodule
```

Important to note also the need for a clock in your design. Most block diagrams at that level will omit the clock as it is assumed but all synchronous elements (memories and registers) will be synchronized to a common clock (or multiple clocks in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

@Unn gives excellent answer, moreover I just want add that, if you not use `read_enable`, Then it may unsynchronised data read operation, It is also preferred to flop the output `read_data` on `read_clk`.

Here with see below templent for reference.

```
parameter RAM_WIDTH = <ram_width>;
parameter RAM_ADDR_BITS = <ram_addr_bits>;

(* RAM_STYLE="{AUTO | BLOCK |  BLOCK_POWER1 | BLOCK_POWER2}" *)
reg [RAM_WIDTH-1:0] <ram_name> [(2**RAM_ADDR_BITS)-1:0];
reg [RAM_WIDTH-1:0] <output_dataB>;

<reg_or_wire> [RAM_ADDR_BITS-1:0] <addressA>, <addressB>;
<reg_or_wire> [RAM_WIDTH-1:0] <input_dataA>;

//  The forllowing code is only necessary if you wish to initialize the RAM 
//  contents via an external file (use $readmemb for binary data)
initial
   $readmemh("<data_file_name>", <ram_name>, <begin_address>, <end_address>);

always @(posedge <clockA>)
   if (<enableA>)
      if (<write_enableA>)
         <ram_name>[<addressA>] <= <input_dataA>;

always @(posedge <clockB>)
   if (<enableB>)
      <output_dataB> <= <ram_name>[<addressB>];
```